# Format tick values in D3

Tags: d3.js, format

I want to display values with floating point in my d3 chart, with two decimal places.
Data values set in floating point format as 12.385, 12.384, 13.627...
I create axis as `yAxisR = d3.axisRight(y3).tickFormat(d3.format(".2f"))` but in axis tick still integer values (12, 13).
If change format for some another value, for example ".0s", axis ticks changes but still not on the that need

https://jsfiddle.net/ochp2dmu/ red right axis

Comment: use the DevTools to see what is inside the svg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works just fine for me in your fiddle.

```
yAxisR = d3.axisRight(y3).tickFormat(d3.format(".2f"))
```

Make sure that you add more of a margin on the right side of your chart in order to see the entire tick label on the right y-axis. It was overflowing off of the window for me, so I changed the right margin to be 40px.

Comment: Yes, it's workin, but... i tried befor axisLeft and it's not displaying. I'm discouraged.

Comment: @AlexanderFresh I don’t understand. Are you able to see the proper formatting on the axis tick labels?

Comment: yes, i see it, thanks.
but I do not understand why when i set yAxisR = d3.axisLeft(y3).tickFormat(d3.format(".2f")) ticks do not display decimal places. i try it befor